# Area of a square equivelent to that of a circle utilizing caclulus

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

So what i did was that i took these two equations $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (equation of a circle) and then along with $|x|+|y|=r$ (equation of a square). Then logically i took the integral of both to get the equation for the area. For $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and $y=r-x$
this is what I got
$$\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2} dx = pi(r^2)$$
$$4\int r-xdx= 2r^2$$
(with boundaries of zero till $r\sqrt{2}$)
although from here i dont understand how can i get the area of these two equations to be equivilent

Comment: You have two different $r$, say $r$ for the circle and $r'$ for the square. Otherwise, your circle and your square will never have the same area

Comment: okay if i do that then how would i still be able to equate both values

Comment: By adjusting the ratio between $r$ and $r'$

Comment: okay and how would one mathematically find the ration between r

 and r′

Comment: What do mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Also, there should be a $4$ in the first equality, too.

Comment: If you want the two areas to be the same, then you should set the two formulae to be equal. This will give you one equation containing both $r$ and $r'$; solve for $\frac{r}{r'}$.